# Web Service Deployment Descriptor

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

What is the purpose of Web Service Deployment Descriptor (wsdd) configuration file. 
If I didn't configure this file explicitly it doesn't create any issue in my application (as I am using a .jws file to do some web service related processes). But, for the first time the application runs, an error is logged in the error log file. The error is as follows: 
"Unable to find config file. Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd". And when the page refreshes or even the application is re-logged in (still the server is running), there won't be any such error log further times. When I use a sample wsdd file in my application, the error is not at all logged in the error log file. I want to know the purpose of this wsdd file and how to configure it based on our application.

Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Marshal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a google on "server-config.wsdd".
e.g. http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/integration-guide.html

It looks like your container or framework is generating a default file if you don't specify one, which is useful, but if you wish to add additional customisations such as handlers, security and logging (etc) then you can specify your own file.
It might be best to use a "bare minimum" file so you can customise it later.